How to remove ### comments from bibtool-generated BibLaTeX file?
bibtool -s -d produces the following output when there are duplicates:
@Article{key
...
}

###Article{key,
...
}

How to remove all the ### entries from the .bib file?

Well, the solution has turned out to be easy: run bibtool -s again.
